# Disable Lync Call links in presence indicators while keeping voice

Tags: lync

We're planning a roll-out of MS Lync without the telephony, for at least the time being. The presence indicators in Outlook and SharePoint include links to call telephone numbers (Call Home..., Call Work..., Call Mobile...) in addition to the voice chat (Call *Name*). Invoking the first set will fail since we are not integrated with the phone system.

Note: These links are only appearing in the presence indicator, not in the Lync client itself.

Is there any way to disable/remove the links for the telephone numbers, while keeping the links for the voice chat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the direct answer but do have some places you can look.  Let us know if you figure it out.

1. In Lync server control panel, set users telephony for pc-to-pc only and they won't be able to call numbers, just lync user's. (after change they need to re login to Lync to see changes)
2. If numbers still show, Lync showing those additional phone numbers is controlled by several things: Lync server import from AD, Lync client sync with Outlook, and manual entry of their own numbers by users in Lync client.  Each way above would likely have a different solution to remove, and you first need to chase down which location they are coming from (likely AD).
3. Maybe Client Policies in Lync Server Control Panel can help you. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg412966.aspx

Comment: The users are all PC-to-PC only. They are pulled from AD, which is desirable, I'm just trying to keep them from instantiating a call that will fail. I'll take a closer look at your third suggestion.  Thanks.

Comment: If there isn't a specific setting that will hide PSTN numbers, then maybe you could use address book normalization rules to intentionally block numbers from getting in.  Basically setting the rules to never match the way you have phone numbers set in AD, so they don't get imported http://blog.schertz.name/2010/09/lync-2010-address-book-normalization/

Comment: Alas, it doesn't appear to apply the normalization to these numbers until you choose to dial. It seems that these numbers are pulled regardless of what is set to import into Lync.